# Clarifications on twisted forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Suppose $F = F(\bar{k})$ is a finite algebraic group over a number field $k$. The absolute Galois group $\Gamma_k$ of $k$ acts on $F$ by group automorphisms via a homomorphism $\rho: \Gamma_k \to S_n$, with $\rho(\Gamma_k)$ normalising $F$ in $S_n$ (note that $S_n$ acts on the *set* $F$ by permutations).

> Why is it true that we can twist $F$ by $\rho$? (I know it *is* true!) For twisting, one should have a 1-cocycle  $\rho: \Gamma_k \to F
> $ . Why is it enough to give a $\rho: \Gamma_k \to S_n$ as above, which is not necessarily even a 1-cocycle?

In general, if $A$ is a $\Gamma_k$-group over $k$ ($\Gamma_k$ acts on $A$ and action is compatible with group structure on $A$), then given a 1-cocycle $\sigma : \Gamma_k \to A$, the twisted form of $A$ by $\sigma$ is given by
$$ A^\sigma:= A \times_k \bar{k} / \{(\gamma, a) \mapsto ^\gamma a \cdot \sigma_\gamma^{-1} \},$$
where the above is the twisted action of $\Gamma_k$ on $A$.